# cake php link to the current page with different prefix

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my default layout I would like to show link which points to the current page but with different prefix. I am using prefix 'language' to use address like www.site.com/eng/controller/action/param.

I tried `$this->Html->link('eng', array('language' => 'eng') );`

But this creates link with url `eng/controller/action` without passed arguments, without named arguments and without url params.

How I can do this? I would prefer elegant solution like 1 line of code - I know it can be done but can't find it :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// helper method, possibly AppHelper, or in AppController and set a view var
function getCurrentParams() {
    $route = Router::currentRoute();
    $params = $this->request->params;
    $pass = $params['pass'];
    $named = $params['named'];
    unset($params['pass'], $params['named']);
    if (!empty($route->options['pass'])) {
        $pass = array();
    }
    return array_merge($params, $named, $pass);
}

$params = $this->SomeHelper->getCurrentParams();
$params['language'] = 'eng';
// use $params for your link now
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case this easy solution worked too!

```
<?php
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
    public function url($url = null, $full = false) {
        if(!isset($url['language']) && isset($this->params['language']) && is_array($url)) {
          $url['language']= $this->params['language'];
        }
        if(count($url) == 1 && isset($url['language'])){
            $params = $this->params;
            $url = array_merge($params['pass'],$url);
        }
        return parent::url($url, $full);
   }
}
```

and in AppController

```
public $helpers = array(
    ...
    'Html' => array('className' => 'MyHtml')
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->Html->link('eng', array('language' => 'eng', 'pass') );`

Comment: I know this - I want to add ALL args passed to current action -> in fact I want link to point to the same url that is the current page but with different prefix...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$url = Router::parse($this->here);
$url['language'='end';
$this->Html->link('eng', $url);
```

It's not one line, but you could compress it into one line but it would be pretty unreadable.

You could wrap it in a helper / function which would be a one line call though ;-)

Comment: Your code doesn't work in 100% - I had to use $this->request->url instead of $this->here because this second returns something before controller name which is parsed as controller name. And I need also GET params in this url...

Comment: Sorry, typed straight into stackoverflow untested. If you need the params you could use array_merge $this->params with $url above